# What is the relevance of seeing $\text{ad}$ as the differential of $\text{Ad}$

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ad}{Ad}$
There are essentially two ways of defining the $\ad$ operator associated to a Lie Group.
The first one is purely theoretical Lie-algebra theoretical, and it's straightfoward, is just defining $\ad(X)(Y)$ as $[X,Y]$, which is readily seen to be a Lie algebra homomorphism into $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$.

This operator is of course very important, as is allows us to extract some information on $\mathfrak{g}$ from is image in $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$, which allows us to use for instance Jordan decompositon on matrices and such.

Of course when we have a Lie group, we have a Lie algebra structure on its tangent space at identity (or on the left invariant tangent fields), and we need to prove that we have a Lie Bracket which amounts usually to define it as the derivative at $0$ of $e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-tX}e^{-tY}$.

However, usually we define the $\ad$ representation in the following manner: we have a morphims $\Ad:G\to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ defined to be $g\mapsto d\text{Conj}(g)(1)$ where $\text{Conj}(g):G\to G$ is the conjugation. Then $\ad$ is simply the differential of $\Ad$

Is there any advantage of definig $\ad$ like that instead of simply definig it as $\ad(X)=[X,\bullet]$.

We can prove of course that it is an equivalent definition, but what is to be gained from defining $\ad$ in this rather convoluted fashion ?
All the theorems that I know about Lie algebra (the ones in Humphreys book for instance), use the fact that $\ad$ is the Lie bracket, and not the fact that is the differential of $\Ad$.

Maybe this is important, to descend Lie algebra representations into actual representations of $G$?

Comment: Are you sure about your proposed alternate definition of the Lie bracket? We should have something like $e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-tX}e^{-tY}\approx (1+tX)(1+tY)(1-tX)(1-tY)=1+t^2[X,Y]+o(t^2).$ So you can't get the Lie bracket by taking the first derivative and setting $t=0$.

I think instead you can define it as $1/2 \frac{d^2}{ds\,dt}[e^{sX},e^{tY}]$ or $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\sqrt{t}X},e^{\sqrt{t}Y}]$. Either way it's more complicated and less natural. 

....

Comment: The adjoint map has the benefit of giving you a representation of both the group and the algebra. And of course you have the problem that your definition requires you to define the exponential map, whereas the definition in terms of the conjugation map/adjoint map requires far less machinery, only the concept of a differential. (I'm not even sure the definition in terms of exponential map is not circular)

Comment: You're right about my definition of the Lie bracket, however you can define it very easily if you view element in the Lie algebra as invariant vector fields, as, simply, the commutator of the (derivation associated to the) invariant vector fields. 
My point being, that usually the Lie Algebra structure is proved way before defining the ad representation, so is there a benefit to not readily define it as $\text{ad}(X)=[X, \bullet]$.

Comment: You are correct that invariant vector fields provide another alternate route to the Lie bracket.

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding on my answer in the comments)

Are you sure about your proposed alternate definition of the Lie bracket? We should have something like $e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-tX}e^{-tY}\approx (1+tX)(1+tY)(1-tX)(1-tY)=1+t^2[X,Y]+o(t^3).$ So you can't get the Lie bracket by taking the first derivative and setting $t=0$.

I think instead you can define it as $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{ds\,dt}[e^{sX},e^{tY}]$ or $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\sqrt{t}X},e^{\sqrt{t}Y}]$. Either way that expression is more complicated and less natural, it's harder to motivate.

And defining the Lie bracket in terms of the exponential map requires quite a bit more machinery, a discussion of uniqueness of solutions to differential equations, whereas the definition in terms of the adjoint map requires only the differential.

> Is there any advantage of definig ad like that instead of simply definig it as ad()=[,∙]?

Seems like a different question. If you only care about the Lie algebra, then you may define the adjoint map solely in terms of its axiomatically given Lie bracket.

But if you want to relate the Lie bracket on a Lie algebra to the group operation on the Lie group of which it is the tangent space, then you need an equation like $[X,Y]=\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{ds\,dt}[e^{sX},e^{tY}]$ or $[X,Y]=d(\text{Ad}(X))(Y).$

Ultimately the first thing you will want to prove about this relation is the functoriality of the Lie algebra functor, $\text{Lie}(G)$ which associates to a Lie group its tangent space endowed with a Lie bracket. The definition of the Lie bracket in terms of the adjoint map makes this check more straightforward than the definition in terms of exponentials.

And the adjoint map has the benefit of giving you a representation of both the group and the algebra.

So to sum up, the definition in terms of the adjoint map is actually simpler, not more convoluted, than the one you propose.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you're saying that defining $\text{ad}$ as the differential of $Ad$, which is itself the differential of the conjugation, is the simplest and more direct way. But for instance, if you have already proven, one way or another, that the tangent space to $0$ of $G$ has a Lie algebra structure (for instance if you work with linear Lie group only, where the definition of the Lie Bracket is straightforward, and you have proved the functoriality of the Lie structure), then there is nothing lost in just defining $ad(X)(Y)$ as $[X,Y]$ ?
Am I correct?

Comment: If you only ever work with subgroups of $GL(n)$ then you lose nothing by treating the lie bracket as a commutator. Because for subgroups of $GL(n)$ the Lie bracket *is* the commutator. But not every Lie group is a subgroup of some $Gl(n)$ so it is nice to have an abstract intrinsic definition. Just like how our definition of a manifold doesn’t require us to consider it a subspace of some ambient space.

Comment: by the way, @Nissokam, if you found the answer helpful you can consider giving it an upvote by clicking on the up arrow, and if you feel that it substantially answered your questions, you can mark it 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark